# "I came to do" vs. "I did"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs

What do we exactly mean when we say that we *came* to do something? Consider these two sentences:

> 1. I authored a book on peace.
> 2. I came to author a book on peace.

Does the second sentence mean that I didn't know that I would author a book, but it turned out that I did?

Comment: No, it doesn't. you might be interested in our sister site: [ell.se]

Comment: I guess second sentence does mean that you did not plan to author a book on peace but somehow you did.

Answer (score 2):

By itself "I came to author a book." does not mean "I didn't know that I would author a book, but it turned out that I did."

By itself "I came to author a book." means that authoring a book is why you are here.

for example:

> Jim: Why are you at this NaNoWriMo meetup?
>   Bob: I came to author a book.

"I came to ..." is often found in snowclones of the threatening phrase

> I came to drink beer and kick ass and I'm all out of beer.

It clearly does not mean that you didn't know you were going to be drinking beer or kicking ass. It clearly shows that drinking beer and kicking ass were why you came.

As part of a larger context, it is possible for "I came to X" to mean that X happened as a result of (possibly coincidental or unexpected) events.

> How I came to author a book is an interesting story.

Answer (score 1):

When we say "I came to..." we mean that at the first opportunity to do something I was unwilling, unable, or unequipped to to do it, but that by some process or sequence of events I became willing, able or equipped, e.g. "I did not like the book at first, but I came to like it after I had read a few chapters".

This is one of many expressions in which we use spatial relativity to refer to chronological relativity: (e.g. "all that is behind me now" to mean that the events are all in the past, and "the challenge ahead" to refer to a time in the imminent future).

"I came to author a book" does not address whether or not you had intended to author a book; that aspect would have to be addressed in another way, such as "Despite my lack of interest in either literature or mathematics, I found myself authoring a book on algebra".